# Password form field in ajax

Tags: html, ajax, passwordbox

What is the ajax/javascript plugin which displays colors next to the password field. So each password will have its own color combination.

Comment: What determines the color? Length? Estimated security? Or is it 'random'?

Comment: its the combination of the characters. So there are usually 3 color strips, if your password is test it will always be red,green,yellow. It's not measuring strength or length of the password

Answer (score 2):

There is no "the one" plugin, but several, each employing its own method of calculating "strength".

[Here](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/10-password-strength-meter-scripts-for-a-better-registration-interface/) is a collection of 10 such plugins.

[Here](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/password_strength) and [here](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/pstrength) are two jQuery plugins in the official repository.